# Assigning chars to a char array with +=

Tags: c++, pointers, char, arrays

Currently I'm writing a rather extensive homework assignment that - among other things - reads a file, builds a binary search tree and outputs it.

Somewhere inside all that I've written a recursive method to output the values of the binary search tree in order.

```
void output(node* n)
{
if(n->leftChild != NULL)
    output(n->leftChild);
cout << n->keyAndValue << " || ";
outputString += n->keyAndValue << '|';
if(n->rightChild != NULL)
    output(n->rightChild);
}
```

No problem with that, but you'll notice the line `outputString += n->keyAndValue << '|';`, because I also want to have all the values inside a char array (I am not allowed to use strings or other more current features of C++) that I can use later on in a different method (e.g. Main method).

The Char-Array is declared as follows:

```
char *outputString;
```

This being just one of the ways I've tried. I also tried using the `const` keyword and just regularly building an array `char outputString[]`. With the version I've shown you I encounter an error when - later on in the program in a different method - calling the following code:

`cout << outputString;`

I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x008c2c2a in BST.exe: 0xC00000005: Access Violation reading location 0x5000000000.

Any clue as to how I'd be able to build a dynamic char array, assign values to it numerous times using `+=` and outputting it without triggering an access violation? I am sorry for asking a rather basic question but I am entirely new to C++.

Thanks and Regards,

Dennis

Comment: Whoever is stopping you from using `std::string` should be taken outside and shot. Every day for a week.

Comment: Are you conclusively proving to the SO community that you are unable to pick up a C++ book and read it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's a homework assignment.

Comment: You cannot append to char pointers like that, not to mention that `outputString += n->keyAndValue << '|'` would not work as written even on an `std::string`. If you are constrained to `char*` it's going to be needlessly hard, but look into creating a "very large" buffer with `malloc` and then appending to it with `strcat`.

Comment: as this is homework I would only point you in the general direction of `malloc` and leave it at that. of course, if it is allowed, you should be using `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: i think you should tag either C or C++, not both as they differ quite a lot.

Comment: What is it that they are teaching you, C or C++ ? Please remove the other tag, then.

Comment: You seem to be guessing what `char*` is and how it can be used. Don't guess. Learn it from decent books. Hint: it's not a char array.

Comment: Is it even necessary to build a string? can't you just directly output the stuff on the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` on pointers does pointer arithmetic, not string concatenation. Eventually you get way beyond your array that `outputString` was pointing to, and trying to print it leads to a segfault.

Since you can't use `std::string`, you need to use `strcat` along with `new[]` and `delete[]` and make sure you allocated your original array with `new[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately, as I stated, I am not allowed to use strings for the sake of doing my homework within the means of the knowledge I should've acquired during the lectures.

Comment: @DennisRöttger sorry, bad reading. You need to just reallocate the array and copy into it whenever you need to concatenate.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that plain C strings need to be `\0`-terminated before being output somewhere via `cout` or `FILE`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that since you can't use `std::string`, you also can't use `new[]`.

You can concatenate strings with a function like this:

```
char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);
    char *result = (char*)malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

This can be done more efficiently, but that probably doesn't matter for homework. And you need to check for errors, etc. etc.

You also need to decide who is going to call `free` on `s1` and `s2`.

For what it is worth, the efficient version looks like this:

```
char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = (char*)malloc(len1+len2+1);
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result+len1, s2, len2);
    result[len1+len2] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

It's more efficient because it only walks the input strings once.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Because I was lazy. Now changed.

Comment: Could certainly do with more `const`, too. Also, shocking myself, since this is C++ I guess you [must cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @unwind Yeah, I slipped into C mode!